# Is there a way to use Wikitude with Nativescript

Tags: angularjs, mobile, nativescript, wikitude

I am working on an app, and the client is convinced that we need to go to the Nativescript path, that sounds fine but we need to make it work with Firebase + Mapbox and Wikitude.

My concern is to be able tu use Wikitude on the project, I cant find information about this.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction, and if this is posible this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at Wikitude SDKs and saw they offer both native Android and iOS versions so you are good to go. NativeScript comes with metadata generators for both Android and iOS so you can use third party SDKs/libraries from JavaScript. I guess the easiest way to go is to create [NativeScript plugin](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins). If you are looking for an example you can take a look at [Firebase plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase).